# How to configure Couchbase connection pool

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I want to configure my connection pool size for Spring Boot Couchbase application, but I can't find any property in order to set it.

A colleague suggested to use (in order to configure queryservice pool)

```
spring.couchbase.env.endpoints.queryservice.min-endpoints=1
spring.couchbase.env.endpoints.queryservice.max-endpoints=5
```

but when i do a netstat it doesn't work. i have 1 socket per node.

[image: netstat to get number of sockets per node]

I am using spring boot.